# Is there a way to get an instance of a class from another project?

Tags: c#, .net

I have three projects:
- Client (Windows Forms)
- Domain (Business logic)
- Service (Server)

The Domain project have AsyncServer that is used by the Service project and AsyncClient that is used by the Client project.

I want that the client to get the same of instance of the service have, because I tried to add the Service as a reference and to make it static and it doesn't work, also I implemented the Singleton Pattern to it, and still doesn't work, because every time when I try to access the Service, it creates a new instance.
So is there a way to get the same instance of the Program class or another class from the Service project?
Thank you!

A part of code from Service project:

**ChatService:**

```
private static ChatService chatService;
private static readonly object syncObject = new object();

public AsyncServer AsyncServer { get; private set; }

private ChatService()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AsyncServer = new AsyncServer();
}

public static ChatService GetInstance()
{
    lock (syncObject)
    {
        if (chatService == null)
        {
            chatService = new ChatService();
        }
    }

    return chatService;
}
```

**Program:** (the service is called with `console` parameter)

```
public static ChatService ChatServer { get; private set; }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args[0] == "console")
    {
        ChatServer = ChatService.GetInstance();
        ChatServer.RunAsConsole(args);
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            ChatService.GetInstance()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
}
```

A part of code from Client project:
**ChatForm:**

```
private void OnConnectButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtIP.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text))
    {
        asyncClient = new AsyncClient(txtIP.Text);
        asyncClient.Connect();
        asyncServer = Service.Program.ChatServer.AsyncServer;
        asyncServer.ChatContentReceivedMethod += DisplayChatContent;
        SetControlsForConnection();
    }
}
```

If I debug the Client project, the ChatServer is null.

Comment: If you use a static field and it's all within the same process, it *should* give you the same instance. It's hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing code. But personally I'd try to avoid global state like this - I'd try to use *dependency injection* instead: provide the instance of the service to the constructor of anything that needs it,.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for your answer, but is not in the same process, because firsly I started the Service and after that the Client, I just added some code.

Comment: So do you mean these are in different *processes*, i.e. you launch them separately? If so, then there's no way they can both refer to the same object (except via remoting or something, but I wouldn't suggest that).

Comment: @JonSkeet Yup, there are two different processes. I want to create a chat, that every time when a user type something, the rest of the clients receive the written messages. I could have the server and client classes in the same project, but I want to run it like a service. How can I do that in other way? Maybe can I use reflection?

Comment: Objects live in memory and processes do not share it. So, even if the processes were on the same machine, you will not be able to share objects. You should consider exposing an interface on your server (web service, web api or even remoting) that can be consumed by the client.

Comment: Maybe this could help:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-chat-server.htm
It explains how to build a simple broadcasting service.

Comment: This looks useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43431682/6996150
Good luck anyway. :-)

Comment: Thanks all for help, but I find another way to do that, here it is: https://github.com/StefanescuEduard/AsynchronousChat, but I don't know if is easier to understand than other solutions.