# C# Multithreading Clients Duplicate Connection/Data Loss

Tags: c#, tcp, server, tcpclient

I am having a weird problem where I am making a chat connection with TCPListeners and sockets. For some reason when a client "connects" to the server it will show they have connected twice. Also what is weird once all of the users have connected I will send out a message to all of them. They will respond back with it acknowledged and state that their chat has started.

Things I am noticing with how i have it setup:

1. It appears according to the log that the user "connects" twice the second "connect occurs once it hits the white(true) loop.
2. When they send over the acknowledgement back to the server not all of the data is getting sent over. If I do a thread sleep on the client it does appear to start working but it is still inconsistent.

Here is the code:

**Server:**

```
private TcpListener tcpListener;
private Thread listen;
private TcpListener tcpUser1, tcpUser2,tcpUser3;
NetworkStream User1Stream,User2Stream,User3Stream;
public event NetworkMessageStringDelegate MessageFromUser;
TcpClient client;

public void start(string ip){

    IpHostEntry host = dns.GetHostEntry(dns.GetHostName());
    IpAddress[] ip = host.AddressList;
    serverStatus = "Server started with IP of: " + ip;
    Thread.Sleep(1);

    tcpUser1 = new TcpListener(IpAddress.Any, 4001);
    listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ListenUser1(tcpUser1)));
    listen.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1);

    tcpUser2 = new TcpListener(IpAddress.Any, 4002);
    listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ListenUser2(tcpUser2)));
    listen.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1);

    tcpUser3 = new TcpListener(IpAddress.Any, 4003);
    listen = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => ListenUser3(tcpUser3)));
    listen.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1);

}

public void ListenUser3(TcpListener tmp){

    tcpListener = (TcpListener)tmp;
    Socket = "Listening for User3";
    tcpUser3.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(2);

    while(true){
        user3 = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Thread user3Thread = new Thread(new ParmeterizedThreadStart(receiveUser3Data));
        user3Thread.Start(user3);
    }
}

//Mostly from MS documenation
private void receiveUser3Data(object client){
    client = (TcpClient)client;
    User3Stream = client.getStream();
    Socket = "Connected to User: " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.toString();
    byte[] message = new byte[4096];
    int total;

    //This is the line it will display the socket message Twice. "Connected to User...."
    while(true){
        total = 0;
        try{
            do{
                total = User3Stream.Read(message,0,4096);
            }
            while(user3.DataAvailable);
        }
        catch()
        {
            Socket = "Error State";
        }
    }
    byte[] infoPacket = new byte[total];
    Array.ConstrainedCopy(message,0,infoPacket,total);
    if(MessageFromUser3 != null){
        MessageFromUser?.Invoke(packet);
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
public void ConfigureUser3(){

    try{
        socket = new Network.TCPIPClient();
        socket.ReceiveMessage() = new Newowrk.TCPIPClient.NetworkMessageStringDelgate(MessageFromserver);
        socket.SendMessage() = new Newowrk.TCPIPClient.NetworkMessageStringDelgate(sendMessage);
        userThread = new Thread(() => socket.Start("0.0.0.0),4054));
        userThread.Start();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
}

//This is where if I sleep it will send but it is still inconsident
private void SendMEssageToSever(object tmpVal){
    object[] sendMessage = tmpVal as object[];
    string tmpSendValue  = tmpVal[0].ToString();
    byte sendValue = Coonvert.ToByte(tmpVal[1]);
    packetData[0] = 0;
    packetData[1] = sendValue;
    packetData[2] = Convert.ToByte(tmpSendValue);

    socket.sendMessage = packetData;
}

private voide sendMessage(byte[] userMessage){
    try{
        if(socket){
            outputMessage.Enqueue(userMessage);
            while(outputMessage.Count > 0){
                Byte[] sendMessage = outputMessage.Dequeue();
                string message = ascII.GetString(sendMessage);
                if(socket.Connected){
                    lock(socket){
                        socket.Send(sendMessage,sendMessage.length,0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
}
```

This code is essentially repeated for all users that are connected to the server.

Comment: This code won't compile. Why are you posting code that won't compile? Look at this: `ParmeterizedThreadStart`. Look at this: `User3Stream = client.getStream();`, also client is of type `object`. Why? Isn't it an extra effort to copy/paste your code and change it here to make it wrong?

Comment: `TcpListener` has asynchronous methods like `BeginAcceptTcpClient`. `TcpClient.GetStream()` (which is a `NetworkStream`) also has asynchronous methods like `BeginRead`. I suggest you change your code to use these and to store the user state in a class and pass this class to and fro between Begin* and End* methods. You can support N number of users then, and don't have to repeat code for each user. You also don't have to have 3 different listeners for 3 connections. HAve one listener and accept clients over this one. The rest is two way communication via `TcpClient.GetStream()`

Comment: @OguzOzgul Do you have time to show an example of what you mean? Guessing you mean something similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431196/c-sharp-tcp-ip-simple-chat-with-multiple-clients

Comment: I have, if you can explain how the code in your question ended up like this :) Do you really have a working source code?

Comment: Yes I do haha. Most of that code was commented out when I put it in there and pasted from the comments since the other working code also didn't work but this was closer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also I followed the link I posted above cause it was making a little bit of sense. My problem I was having trouble understanding there is how to keep that thread alive for more data from the server or sending data to the server.

Comment: I am preparing your medicine. Patience (~15min)

Answer (score 1):

The TcpListener has asynchronous methods like `BeginAcceptTcpClient`.

TcpClient.GetStream() (which is a NetworkStream) also has asynchronous methods like `BeginRead`.

I suggest you change your server code to use these and to store the user state in a class and pass this class to and fro between `Begin*` and `End*` methods.

You can support N number of users then, and don't have to repeat code for each user. You also don't have to have 3 different listeners for 3 connections. Have just one listener and accept clients over this one. The rest is two-way communication via `TcpClient.GetStream()`

Here is a minimal server example which listens on port 9988 (for only LoopBack, which means the local machine). You can of course change this.

There is no client example here. Only the server. Just copy/paste the code into your program.cs file in a console application.

I hope the comments are sufficient to explain the code.

I hope also, that this helps.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the state for a client connection
    /// </summary>
    public class ClientState
    {
        public const int ReceiveBufferSize = 8192;
        // The buffer to receive in
        internal byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[ReceiveBufferSize];

        // The TcpClient instance representing the remote end (connected client)
        public TcpClient TcpClient { get; set; }

        public byte[] GetReceiveBuffer()
        {
            return receiveBuffer;
        }
    }

    // This method is invoked when data is received from a client
    static void OnReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // The state parameter passed to the BeginRead method
        // is provided here in the asyncResult.AsyncState property
        ClientState clientState = asyncResult.AsyncState as ClientState;

        int numberOfBytesReceived = clientState.TcpClient.GetStream().EndRead(asyncResult);

        if (numberOfBytesReceived == 0)
        {
            // This means that the transmission is over
            Console.WriteLine("Client disconnect: {0}", clientState.TcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
            return;
        }

        // Now the receiveBuffer is filled with <numberOfBytesReceived> bytes received from the client.
        // Do whatever is needed here.
        Console.WriteLine("Received {0} bytes from {1}", numberOfBytesReceived, clientState.TcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
        // We are also sending some information back:
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(clientState.TcpClient.GetStream());
        streamWriter.WriteLine("The server has received {0} bytes from you! Keep up the good job!", numberOfBytesReceived);
        streamWriter.Flush();

        // Begin read again
        clientState.TcpClient.GetStream().BeginRead(clientState.GetReceiveBuffer(), 0, ClientState.ReceiveBufferSize, OnReceive, clientState);
    }

    // This method is invoked when a new client connects
    static void OnConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // The state parameter passed to the BeginAcceptTcpClient method
        // is provided here in the asyncResult.AsyncState property
        TcpListener tcpListener = asyncResult.AsyncState as TcpListener;

        // Accept the TcpClient:
        TcpClient newClient = tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);

        // Immediately begin accept a new tcp client.
        // We do not want to cause any latency for new connection requests
        tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnConnect, tcpListener);

        // Create the client state to store information aboutn the client connection
        ClientState clientState = new ClientState()
        {
            TcpClient = newClient
        };

        Console.WriteLine("A new client has connected. IP Address: {0}", newClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint);

        // Start receiving data from the client
        // Please note that we are passing the buffer (byte[]) of the client state
        // We are also passing the clientState instance as the state parameter
        // this state parameter is retrieved using asyncResult.AsyncState in the asynchronous callback (OnReceive)
        newClient.GetStream().BeginRead(clientState.GetReceiveBuffer(), 0, ClientState.ReceiveBufferSize, OnReceive, clientState);

        // Nothing else to do.
        // The rest of the communication process will be handled by OnReceive()
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Start a tcp listener
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 9988);
        tcpListener.Start();

        // Begin accept a new tcp client, pass the listener as the state
        // The state is retrieved using asyncResult.AsyncState in the asynchronous callback (OnConnect)
        tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnConnect, tcpListener);

        // That's it. We don't need anything else here, except wait and see.
        Console.WriteLine("Server is listening on port 9988. Press enter to stop.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: So really my Start() would no longer be needed. And then keep my client code the same?

Comment: There is more to it than to just getting rid of the Start() method. 1. You will not be creating and maintaining any threads yourself. 2. Wou will not be having only three clients, and will not have to listen on three different ports. 3. You will be doing asynchronous programming, (The old way).. I don't have time to examine your client code. You can use the GetStream().BeginRead method on the client also, but when a client is a windows form application and has a single user, you may choose a blocking approach there (but not on the main thread of course)

Comment: A very important note here; when you get an exception on a thread that is not a WorkerThread (Thread.Start(), or any old school asynchronous callback methods) your application will crash. Please keep this in mind.

Comment: You can enrich the ClientState to have any information regarding the remote client. It can represent a player playing your multi-player game, or a chat client, etc. This allows you, for instance, to add methods for handling and processing the received data (eg: clientState.ProcessRequest(byte[] request).

Comment: I am doing an edit now because I realized a race condition in my code. I am moving `BeginRead` in `OnReceive` to the end, because we don't want to receive new data and override the receiveBuffer while we are working on it.

Comment: Isn't it possible newClient will be cleaned up by garbage collection and disappear?

Comment: Hi. It's highly unlikely. But you have a good point there. If a client suddenly stops sending data (but is still connected), we loose him. This implementation is the very basics of a server . You should keep track of your clients (filling them in a dictionary etc.) as any server app should do. My answer is only to elaborate on the async messaging part.

Comment: Since we glue it to the BeginRead method as the user state, the ClientState will not be collected by GC. When EndRead is called we get it back. But if we don't glue it again, GC will collect it, that's true. But GC is not the main point here. Even if GC does not collect it, we have no reference to it. That's why we need to keep track of clients as an additional feature. We can then start sending pings (keep-alives), can send spontenaus notifications ("A new person entered the room") etc.

Comment: It is also possible to do a blocking implementation once a client is connected. The `OnConnect` method is invoked on a separate thread. Instead of using BeginRead and EndRead, you can go synchronously here (As you do in your threads) because they will not be blocking the main thread.